# using Regex to extract strings from HTML tags

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

---

Hello

I'm trying to get all the variables from an underscore template, so in this string :

```
 <%=userID %> </td><td><%=username %> </td><td><%=firstname %>
```

I'd like to get an array :

```
{userID, username,firstname}
```

**Some notes :**

1. I can't assume there are any spaces in the string.
2. Variable names can repeat themselves in the template.
3. html tags can vary, this is simply an example. the template can be based on 's or  or anything else.

**What I tried** :

```
    var regexp = /<%=(.+)%>/;
```

**Why it failed**

The above Regexp would get the initial string as well, as it fits the requirements of the regexp. I'm not too experienced with Regexp's and I'm afraid i'm missing something really simple.

I also know that in general it's bad practice to parse HTML with regex, however this specific example isn't exactly HTML parsing (in my opinion), as I don't need a specific html tag.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use brackets for grouping and use character classes to limit the matched characters. Try:

```
    var regexp = /<%=([\w\s]+)%>/g;
    var html = "<%=userID %> </td><td><%=username %> </td><td><%=firstname %>";
    var match = [], result = [];

    while (match = regexp.exec(html))
        result.push(match[1].trim());
    console.log("Result = " + result);

    // Result = userID,username,firstname
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, 

This returns the first variable only, while running it in a .exec while loop, it hangs as an infinite loop.
(each iteration brings back exactly the same data.

Comment: you might be running the loop incorrectly. i've revised my answer to include a complete implementation.

Comment: Your loop works, and everything is indeed fine, I'll dive into that regex and find out why it works exactly.

As to my previous loop that failed, I was using the MDN docs ;
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec


while ((myArray = myRe.exec(str)) !== null)

removing the null part fixed it. 
Thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to:

```
<%=(.+?)%>
```

`?` is a lazy matcher.

Comment: Same as the answer below : 

Unfortunately it doesn't work, 

This returns the first variable only, while running it in a .exec while loop, it hangs as an infinite loop.
(each iteration brings back exactly the same data.